# Mathematical Induction Question About A Basis Step

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use mathematical induction to show that:

$1^3 + 3^3 + 5^3 + ... + (2n + 1)^3 = (n+1)^2(2n^2+4n+1)$ whenever $n$ is a positive integer.

I am able to solve this problem, but the thing that confuses me on this is the Basis Step.

P(1): $(2(1) + 1)^3$ $\neq$ $4(7)$, does this mean that this problem can not be proved using mathematical induction, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Don't start at n= 1.  Start at n = 0.

Comment: Be careful: $1^3+(2\cdot 1 + 1)^3 = 4\cdot 7$, you missed the $1^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start at $n = 1$.  Start at $n=0$.

$P(n = 0): (1)^3  = (0 + 1)\left(2\times0^2 + 4*0 + 1\right) =1$

$P(1): 1 + 3^3 = 2^2\times\left(2 + 4 + 1\right)$

Answer (score 1):

**Method -1: Mathematical Induction**

Notice, the following steps by Mathematical Induction

1. Setting $n=1$, we get 
   $$1^3+(2\cdot 1+1)^3=(1+1)^2(2(1)^3+4(1)+1)$$
   $$28=28$$
   The identity holds good for $n=1$.
2. Assume that it holds for $n=k$ then we have 
   $$1^3+3^3+5^3+\ldots +(2k+1)^3=(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1)$$
3. Setting $n=k+1$, we get 
   $$1^3+3^3+5^3+\ldots +(2k+1)^3+(2k+3)^3=(k+1+1)^2(2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)+1)$$

$$\implies 1^3+3^3+5^3+\ldots +(2k+1)^3=(k+2)^2(2k^2+8k+7)-(2k+3)^3$$
$$=2k^4+8k^3+11k^2+6k+1$$ $$=(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1)$$
Which is true from (2)

Hence, the given identity holds true for all positive integers $n\geq 1$

**Method-2**

Notice, we have
$$1^3+3^3+5^3+\dots +(2n+1)^3$$ 
$$=(1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+5^3+\dots +(2n)^3+(2n+1)^3)-(2^3+4^3+6^3+\ldots +(2n)^3)$$ 
$$=(1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+5^3+\dots +(2n)^3+(2n+1)^3)-8(1^3+2^3+3^3+\ldots +n^3)$$ 
$$=\left(\frac{(2n+1)((2n+1)+1)}{2}\right)^2-8\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$ 
$$=(n+1)^2(2n+1)^2-2n^2(n+1)^2$$ 
$$=(n+1)^2[(2n+1)^2-2n^2]$$ 
$$=(n+1)^2[4n^2+1+4n-2n^2]$$
$$=(n+1)^2(2n^2+4n+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for $n=1$ your sum is $1^3+3^3$ and you are interpreting it as $3^3$ only. So the LHS for P(1) is $1^3+3^3=28$ and the RHS is $4(7)=28$.

You should prove P(0) first by the way. The LHS in that case is $1^3=1$ and the RHS is $1(1)=1$.

Comment: Is it okay for me to Prove P(0) even though in the question it states that $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: @J.Andrews: IMHO the question is badly framed (although technically correct). If you prove P(1) you are ultimately establishing the result where the sum in question has at least two terms. There is no extra hard work involved if you prove P(0) and thereby establish a stronger result (where the sum has at least one term).

Comment: You can start from n = 1, *if* you tack on the $1^3$ to the first sum.  It is badly framed.